# Geometric issue regarding javascript to highlight menu items while page scrolls

Tags: jquery, algorithm, math, geometry, logic

On the development of a one-page-layout I've tried to create and use third party scripts to highlight the current menu item while page scrolls, basically using jQuery offset and scrollTop properties. Regardless of the tech involved, most of the solutions rely over a basic logic represented by this pseudo-algorithm:

```
FOR EACH page section DO{
   IF (scroll top >= page section top) THEN{
      HIGHLIGHT THE RESPECTIVE MENU ITEM
      BREAK
   }
}
```

This works fine when you have large page sections, larger then your window height. But once you have smaller sections you can have a situation where two (or more) sections are displayed on your window. This is when this logic starts to fail, since it is desirable to highlight only one menu item at a time, never two. For instance:

- You can click on a menu item, the page scrolls to it, but then the previous/next section is also displayed, leading your script to highlight an unexpected menu item.
- You scroll somewhere along the the page expecting some menu item to be highlighted but the previous/next is chosen since their respective sections are being displayed as well.

I wonder if there is another pseudo algorithm considering the **window height**, the **section height**, the **scroll direction**, and some **other** geometric evaluation to chose the appropriate menu item to be highlighted considering that two or more sections are displayed on the window.

Here is some very basic code to test ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/odon/59dpS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do:

```
next-section-top = page-section-top + page-section-height;

IF (scroll-top >= page-section-top && scroll-top < next-section-top) {
      HIGHLIGHT page-section MENU ITEM
}
```

**edit:**
you're right - above will not cover small sections at the bottom... but this one will cover all possible cases:

```
var scrollPosition = scrollTop + (scrollTop/maxScroll*windowHeight);
IF (scrollPosition >= page-section-top && scrollPosition < next-section-top) {....}
```

in your code - it will be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TFJ8P/5/

Comment: yeah it didn't work well - but i edited answer - it will do now ;)